# how do I change the azure function cron expression at the deployment time?

Tags: azure

how do I change the azure function CRON expression at the deployment time?

we want to change the CRON expression value of the azure function from one environment to another environment how do I do that?

e.g.: on
DEV --> "0 5 * * * *"
on
TEST --> "0 * * * * *"
on
UAT  --> "0 5 * * * *"

What changes I need to make to my CICD pipeline (Yaml file) to make this possible.
here is the same

```
- stage: 
displayName: TST
jobs:
- deployment: TST
  displayName: deploy funtion app to Test
  environment: 'deploy-tst'
  strategy:
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - download: current 
          artifact: [artifact-name]

        - task: AzureFunctionApp@1
          inputs:
            azureSubscription: '[azure-subscription-name]'
            appType: 'functionApp'
            appName: '[function-app-name]'
            package: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)/**/*.zip'
            deploymentMethod: 'runFromPackage'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%EmailScheduleTriggerTime%` (or any other setting name) in your time trigger function and move the setting to a configuration file. In your case, during the release you'll set the correct value for the property in you azure app service setting.

e.g.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "EmailScheduleTriggerTime": "0 30 9-12 * * *", //Run every  30 minutes from 9:00 to 12:00

  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": ""
  }
}

[FunctionName("TimerfunctionApp")] 
public static void Run([TimerTrigger("%EmailScheduleTriggerTime%")] TimerInfo TInfo, TraceWriter log)
```