# Make timer trigger function cron configurable from Azure DevOps release pipeline

Tags: azure, function, azure-devops, cron, azure-deployment

I have one Timer trigger Azure function which runs on each 10 mins, cron is 0 */10 * * * *

I want to make this cron configurable from Azure release pipeline while deployment.

I have added the cron value in library variable like below,

[image]

**I have used the same library variable in App settings of release pipeline.**

[image]
[image]

If I try to deploy, it is showing the error in log like below.
[image]

I understood the error. The error is because during deployment the corn is splitted like below. But not sure how to solve the error so that the corn will not be splitted. Find the below log from release log in bold.

**Trying to update App Service Application settings. "CornValue":"0","":"*"**

Comment: Hello @Abhishek, Could you please try to use the expession `0 */10 * ? * *`  let me know if it helps

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT, no luck :( 
I am getting the same error as before. 

2022-03-30T06:45:71.3558572Z ##[error]Error: Failed to update App service 'applicationName' application settings. Error: BadRequest - Parameter name cannot be empty. (CODE: 400)

Comment: Could you please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63826418/how-do-i-change-the-azure-function-cron-expression-at-the-deployment-time

Comment: @AjayKumarGhose-MT, that is done in code part and locally working fine.

but while deployment we have to inject the value for the same.

I have already done like:::
        public async Task Run([TimerTrigger("%CronValue%")] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
. but issue I am getting while deployment

Comment: It seems you need to provide the name as on your .json file  in my case its `schedule`  and `value(0 */10 * ? * *)`

Comment: I am providing exactly the same as on my .json 

Can you pls show me the release pipeline you have?
Did you configure the cron value in Azure DevOps library and using the same in release pipeline under app settings?

Comment: I have not configure my pipeline yet, Could you please try to deploy without adding any cron expression in your `appsettings`

Comment: I have fixed the issue in pipeline as well. Thnx for responding @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Comment: Could you please share with us the details of how do you fix to help other community members

Comment: I have already added in the answer section @AjayKumarGhose-MT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is solved and able to inject the value in from Pipeline as well.

Need to add double quotes for the value of cron in release pipeline, then the cron value will be put as is, it will not be splitted

[image]

Comment: i f****** love you man!